# "bool" не содержит определение для "Select"

Tags: c#, linq

Что не так с кодом?

```
 public static bool ParseDir(string directory)  //вызываем этот метод
    {   
           bool isRDK = false;              
       Directory.GetFiles(directory)
                 .Select(file => new FileInfo(file))
                 .Any(f => f.Extension == ".rdk")
                 .Select(f => f.FullName)
                 .ToList()
                 .ForEach(x => { 
                     Console.WriteLine(x);
                     FileParser.ExportFile(x);
                     isRDK = true;

                 });
       return isRDK;

    }
```

Почему ругается: "bool" не содержит определение для "Select"

Comment: Не стоит использовать императивные конструкции с LINQ-запросами.
Я бы написал так:

    var filteredFileNames =
            Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory)
                     .Where(path => Path.GetExtension(path) == ".rdk");
    foreach (var path in filteredFileNames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(path);
        FileParser.ExportFile(path);
        isRDK = true;
    }

Comment: Согласен, исходный код очень тяжело читается.

Answer (score 6):

Потому что строка

.Any(f => f.Extension == ".rdk")

Возвращает bool а вы для него (см след строку) вызываете `.Select(...)`

Решение: вместо `.Any(f => f.Extension == ".rdk")` поставьте `.Where(f => f.Extension == ".rdk")`